# Counting word pairs from a text file [Python]

Tags: python

So from a text file which has a content:

***Lemonade juice whiskey beer soda vodka***

In Python, by implementing that same .txt file, I would like to output word-pairs in the next order:

- juice-lemonade
- whiskey-juice
- beer-whiskey
- soda-beer
- vodka-soda

I managed outputing something like that by using list instead of opening file in Python, but in the case with some major .txt file, that is not really a handy solution.
Also, the bonus task for this would be to output the probability for each of those pairs. Any kind of hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Fidia; welcome to SO; it would be great if you could provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried and where you're stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you should normally ask one question at a time. If your question has multiple parts, it's best to break it up into 2 minimal examples and ask separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read large files efficiently, you should read them line-by-line, or (if you have really long lines, which is what the snippet below assumes) token-by-token.

A clean way to do this [while keeping an open handle](https://www.oreilly.com/content/2-great-benefits-of-python-generators-and-how-they-changed-me-forever/) on a file is by using [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) that yield a word at a time.

You can have another generator that combines 2 words at a time and yields pairs.

```
from typing import Iterator

def memory_efficient_word_generator(text_file: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    word = ''
    with open(text_file) as text:
        while True:
            character = text.read(1)
            if not character:
                return
            if character.isspace():
                yield word.lower()
                word = ''
            else:
                word += character


def pair_generator(text_file: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    previous_word = ''
    for word in memory_efficient_word_generator(text_file):
        if previous_word and word:
            yield f'{previous_word}-{word}'
        previous_word = word or previous_word


for pair in pair_generator('filename.txt'):
    print(pair)
```

Assuming `filename.txt` contains:

> Lemonade juice whiskey beer soda vodka
>
> cola tequila lemonade juice

You should see something like:

```
lemonade-juice
juice-whiskey
whiskey-beer
beer-soda
soda-vodka
vodka-cola
cola-tequila
tequila-lemonade
lemonade-juice
```

Of course, there's a lot more you should handle depending on your desired behaviour (for example, handling non-alphabetic characters in your input).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the feedback.
That's pretty much it, I just added encoding = 'utf-8' here:

```
with open(text_file, encoding='utf-8') as text:
```

since it outputs error for 'charmap' for me.

And just one more thing, I also wanted to output the number of the elements(words) from the text file by using:

```
file = open("filename.txt", "rt", encoding="utf8")
data = file.read()
words = data.split()

print('Number of words :', len(words))
```

which I did, now I'm trying to do the same with those word-pairs that you sent, basically each of those pairs would be one element, like for example:

lemonade-juice ---> one element

So if we would to count all of these from a text file:

```
lemonade-juice
juice-whiskey
whiskey-beer
beer-soda
soda-vodka
vodka-cola
cola-tequila
tequila-lemonade
lemonade-juice
```

we would get the output of 9 elements or

```
Number of word-pairs: 9
```

Was thinking now to try to do that with using `len` function and calling `text_file`.
Fix me if I'm looking in a wrong direction.

Once again, thank you for your time.

Comment: Hello again @Fidia; please do not post questions in the answers section. Your approach seems fine for small files. For large files, you can count words/pairs in the appropriate generator (`var += 1`).